# Rotated copies for spiral wireframe

Tags: plotting, mesh, style

```
coord[th_] = {Sech[th]*Cos[th + v], Sech[th]*Sin[th + v], Tanh[th]};
loxo45 = ParametricPlot3D[coord[th], {th, 0, Pi}, {v, .0, 2 Pi},   
PlotLabel -> "3_D WirePlt", PlotStyle -> {Thick, Yellow},PlotRange -> All]
```

Using `ListPlot3D` or otherwise please help show how to avoid parallel lines and also the surface so that only the spirals are visible? (Like in `ParametricPlot3D` but with multiple rotated lines)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this (play with `Mesh`):

```
loxo45 = ParametricPlot3D[coord[th], {th, 0, Pi}, {v, .0, 2 Pi}, 
PlotLabel -> "3 _D WirePlt", PlotStyle -> None, PlotRange -> All, 
Mesh -> {0, 20}, MeshStyle -> {{}, {Red, Thickness[0.01]}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

#### Single-parameter ParametricPlot3D

```
ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate @ Table[coord[th], {v, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/20}], {th, 0, Pi}, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick]]
```

[image]

#### RotationTransform

```
line = ParametricPlot3D[coord[th] /. v->0, {th, 0, Pi}, PlotStyle->Directive[Thick, Red]];
Graphics3D[Table[GeometricTransformation[line[[1]], RotationTransform[a, {0, 0, 1}]], 
 {a, Range[0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/20]}], Axes -> True]
```

[image]

If you wish make `Line`s into `Tube`s:

```
% /. Line -> (Tube[#, .02] &)
```

[image]

Comment: very nice adds, +1

Comment: Thank you @JoséAntonioDíazNavas.